# GeoCode filter in mongoose elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

I am trying to do geo point filter in mongodb in meanjs. i have used mongoosastic modules but i am not able to perform geo point filter.
here below are the mongoose schema and controller code for filter.

Mongoose schema

```
    'use strict';
    /**
     * Module dependencies.
     */
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
            Schema = mongoose.Schema,
            mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic');

    var BusinessSchema = new Schema({
        name: {type: String, unique: 'Name already exists', trim: true, required: 'Name is required.', es_indexed: true},
        searchTags: {type: [String], es_indexed: true},
        alias: {type: Array, es_indexed: true},
        // geoLocation: { type: [Number], /*/ [<longitude>, <latitude>]*/ index: '2d', /*/ create the geospatial index,*/ required: 'GeoLocation is required.', es_indexed:true,es_type:'geo_point'},
        geo_cords: {
            type: Array
        },
        address: {
            address1: {type: String, required: 'Address is required', trim: true},
            address2: String,
            city: {type: String, required: 'City is required', trim: true},
            // state: {type: String, required: 'State is required', trim: true},
            country: {type: String, required: 'Country is required', trim: true},
            postalCode: {type: String, required: 'Postal code is required', trim: true},
            neighbourhood: String
        },
        isActive: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
            es_indexed: true
        },
        dateUpdated: {
            type: Date
            , es_indexed: true
        },
        dateCreated: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
            , es_indexed: true

        }
    });
```

controller code for filter and query

```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        Business = mongoose.model('Businesses');

    var query = {
        "query_string": {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": categoryIds.join(' OR '),
                "fields": ["categoryIds", "relatedCategoryIds"]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {"term": {"address.postalCode": "110016"}},
                    {"geo_distance": {
                            "distance": "50km",
                            "geo_cords": [-122.3050, 37.9174]
                        }
                    }
                ],
            }
        }
    }

    Business.search(query, function (err, results) {
        // sendResponse(req, res, err, results)
        if (!err) {
            res.json(results);
        } else {
            res.status(400).send({message: 'Business Not Found'})
        }
    });
```

while doing this i am getting a long error saying

```
QueryParsingException[[businessess] failed to find geo_point field [geo_cords]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of [mongoosastic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoosastic#mapping)

> **Geo mapping**
>
> Prior to index any geo mapped data (or calling the synchronize), the mapping must be manualy created with the createMapping (see above).

First, in your schema, define 'geo_cords' this way:

```
geo_cords: : {
      geo_point: {
        type: String,
        es_type: 'geo_point',
        es_lat_lon: true
      },
      lat: { type: Number },
      lon: { type: Number }
    }
```

Add an es_type: 'object' to each Array or embbeded type

```
alias: {type: Array, es_indexed: true, es_type: 'object'}
```

Then call .createMapping() on the model just after you've created it.